# How to avoid HTML function error in rmd to word

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to create a word document with the reproducible code below, however I get this error message. How can I fix this problem? This error however goes away when I remove the first chunk. The sample LiDAR file can be downloaded form [here](https://app.box.com/s/tgrekw8trgcug7gri4ol3otahvhdohlo).

Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

````
 ---
    title: "Untitled"
    author: "Mandalorian"
    date: "3/29/2021"
    output: word_document
    ---
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    
  library(lidR)
    ```
    # Chunk 1
    ```{r First load the data,echo=FALSE}
    
    # Bring in the LAZ file 
    Als_P6_Sub_Ori = readLAS("~/als_plot_6_sub.laz")
    
    # Inspect this file to see the quality control information which is quite useful
    las_check(Als_P6_Sub_Ori)
    
    # Create LASCatalog
    ctg = catalog("~")
    # Plot
    plot(ctg)
    plot(ctg, mapview = TRUE, map.type = "Esri.WorldImagery")
    # Turns out that the LAZ file does not have a CRS 
    # Summary check
    summary(Als_P6_Sub_Ori)
    #Als_P6_Sub_Ori@data$Classification
    
    ```
    # Chunk 2
    #Task 1
    
    bla bla bla (some text in Word)
    
    ```{r Task 1 screenshot,pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="ABC"}
    
    
    knitr::include_graphics("~")
    
    
    ```
````

Comment: Can you please try to post a [mre]? Minimal: not all the code you posted is required to reproduce your problem. Reproducible: People trying to help you should be able to *run* your code. This is not possible with all the external files your code relies on. My *guess*: `plot()` (specifically, `plot.LAScatalog`) is the culprit.

Comment: @CL I have made the required changes to the code, and also provided the file used in the code as the package itself doesn't come with sample data. Hope this works now.

Comment: I think `plot(ctg, mapview = TRUE, map.type = "Esri.WorldImagery")` is the problem here. It produces an HTML output

Comment: @JRR is there a way to have the plot from the line you mentioned by using some other method/function white knitting to .docx?

Comment: Maybe try https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/reference/mapshot.html